# Nginx load balancer as geoip based traffic router

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, geoip, maxmind

I have configured nginx load balancer with geoip to redirect traffic based on request user ip.
its simply picking ip of user and redirect traffic to closer continental server.
**107.155.95.202** ip of load balancer, kindly hit it in browser.

but its also changing load balancer ip to that specific server ip, which is not i want,
i want load balancer ip should not be changed only traffic routed to specific server.

also there is no real server for now, server are on same placed, but future goal is to automatically accommodate more servers from all over the world, and when user hit above given ip, it should redirect traffic to closet server.
its my first question here, i am expecting pro's here to rescue, thanks in advance.

**Configurations for routing traffic based on user ip.**

```
map $geoip_city_continent_code $closest_server {
  default localhost;
  EU      104.254.128.58;
  AS      66.165.238.218;
}

server {
  server_name localhost
              104.254.128.58;
              66.165.238.218;

  if ($closest_server != $host) {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$closest_server$request_uri break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this yourself?  These days, CDNs are very cheap, with nodes worldwide, anycast support, simple config, etc.

Comment: but for specific countries like Australia and indonesia according to my client they don't have any servers over there, otherwise aws was best option, also I was looking into anycast thingy, but i dont know how to implement it, there is no solid documentation available for it with nginx.

Comment: There are a lot of CDNs to choose from.  Even if you did stick to AWS CloudFront, your client is wrong... you can see a map of all their PoPs:  https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/?nc=sn&loc=2